# Posting MultiPartFileData file to a function

Tags: c#, file-upload, dotnet-httpclient

I have data coming from a source to my Api and I need to post it to another `POST` ActionResult.

I have no problem in receiving data in first function which is basically this;

```
var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
try
{
    //irrelevant confirmations and other code pieces are left out
    await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
    foreach (MultipartFileData fileData in provider.FileData)
    {
        var appPath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();
        var basePath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(appPath, @"..\"));
        var headerActivityPath = basePath + "\\Documents\\" + tenantString + "\\Activity\\" + activityId;
        File.Copy(fileData.LocalFileName, Path.Combine(activityPath, fileName));
    }
}
```

I need to make an POST after this one finishes receiving the file. I want to make it without saving it to disk first, so I don't know where I should do the `POST` request with `HttpClient`.

The ActionResult with will be receiving the data has a parameter with `HttpPostedFileBase` but I don't know what to send it.

Every method I used before uses a file on the disk, is it possible to do this without saving the file to disk first?

Answer (score 0):

`HttpPostedFileBase` has a property on it called `InputStream` this will give you access to the content of the attachment which was uploaded to your endpoint. You can use this as the argument to a new StreamContent in the `HttpClient`.

```
foreach (MultipartFileData fileData in provider.FileData)
    {
        await client.PostAsync("http://someurl.com", new StreamContent(fileData.InputStream));
    }
```

Comment: filedata.InputStream gives "'MultiPartFileData' does not contain a definition for 'InputStream' and no accesible extension method 'InputStream' accepting a first argument of type 'MultipartFileData' could be found ..." error.